# Delete all files that contain strings

Tags: windows, file, cmd, grep, delete-file

I have around 40,000 files, and a list of identifiers.

eg:
AB000001,
AB000002,
AB000004,
AB000005,
AB000006,
AB000007

Each file should contain an identifier (not in the file name) and I need to find all files that aren't in my list.

I believe the best thing to do is run a small program or command to delete all files that contain any of my list of identifiers.

So after I've run the command/program I'll be left with a file that conatins AB000003.

Does anyone know of a technique or free software that already exisits that would help me achieve this, rather than writing something from scratch.

Edit: Forgot to add that the files are .xml and I have a lot of identifiers (35,000) so can't really do it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have your identifiers in a text each Id in a new line, then do the following:

```
for /F "tokens=* delims=*" %E in (identifiers.txt) DO (grep -l "%E" *.xml)
```

You can redirect output to `>> %E.txt` so you get the results per Identifier

Comment: This sounds perfect for what I asked for, so I'll put it as the accepted answer. However I solved it in the end, as I had my XML still in a DB, so I queried against it after loading my indentifiers into a table.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `list.txt` file that contains all identifiers that you need to match.
Then, without using third party software but using [FINDSTR](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html), you can get all the names of the files that do not contain a match:

```
findstr /L /V /G:list.txt *.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

[Grep for Windows](http://www.wingrep.com/) looks like the beast for the job. It stands to reason that you could just employ *nix-like grep commands to get the job done.

The evaluation version is fully-functional.

You could probably...

```
grep -l "AB000003" *
```

to list the files you want to identify.

Comment: My only problem is the sheer number of identifiers I have to look over. And I only have a list of identifiers that I don't need if you know what I mean. Ie, I don't know AB000003. I just know everything I don't want.

Comment: I would definitely consider moving them, if only temporarily. Then it's just a process with a finite number of steps, i.e. the number of ID's to 'eliminate'. What you're left with is the answer to life, the universe, and everything.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. I don't mind moving them, that's fine. I just need to be able to find the ones I need to move.

Comment: And the fakey grep software I referred to above won't cut it?

Comment: I don't think so. I need something that can read in my 35,000 identifiers. I think I'm going to have to write something myself.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you're saying. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Prepare a text file containing your list of IDs, one ID per line. Call it ID.LIST

```
AB000001
AB000002
AB000004
AB000005
AB000006
AB000007
etc.
```

Using the free [gnu grep for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm), the following command will list all xml files that do not contain any of the ID strings. I added the -w option (match whole words) to prevent "AB000001" from matching something like "AB0000011".

```
grep -L -w -f ID.LIST *.xml
```